# Test for onclick function not working in react. Returning Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Test for onclick function not working in react. Returning Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined. Below i have written sample code.

my page : myComponent.js

```
const myComponent = () => {

     const backToDashboard = async ({history})=>{
        history.push("/home");
     }

    const submitResponse = async props => {
      /* url calling here */
      backToDashboard(props)
    }

   return (
       <Button
          className="submitResponse"
          onClick={()=>submitResponse(props)}
        >
          submit Complete
        </Button>
     )
  }
}
```

export default myComponent ;

This is the code i have tried.
test file :

```
    import myComponent from "./myComponent ";

    describe("Container", () => {
      const mockHistory = {
        location: {
          pathname: "/home",
        },
         push: jest.fn()
      };

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = mount(
          <MemoryRouter>
            <Provider store={mockStore(mockInitialState)}>
              <myComponent history={mockHistory} />
            </Provider>
          </MemoryRouter>
        );
      });
    it("should redirect page on click of submitResponse", () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitResponse ');
        const submitButton = wrapper.find(".submitResponse");
        submitButton.simulate("click");
       expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

      });
});
```

**Error :  TypeError: Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined**

Comment: Are you able to find submitButton correctly?

Comment: yes.i have consoled it. Even click is also  working fine

Comment: when i ran the test , i am able to get control inside backToDashboard function. so i tried to mock history.push as well.But that also returning error

Comment: Do the button callbacks need to be declared `async`? That may be messing with your tests if it is expecting synchronous callback to be called (though the spy my help here).

Comment: Or you can try using my answer that I provided and also before you simulate click you can try calling wrapper.update() and also check if it helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one observation I'd make is that maybe you're not testing the right thing?

The test you're currently writing will break if someone changes the 'submitResponse' function name for example - but the functionality may not be broken from a user's perspective.

I'd suggest testing the fact the API call happens when the button is clicked (spy on `fetch` or whatever) and also that the user is pushed to the dashboard route. That way, you can change the implementation details as much as you like, and as long as the functionality itself does not change, your test will continue to pass :).

```
describe("Container", () => {
  const mockHistory = {
    location: {
      pathname: "/home",
    },
     push: jest.fn()
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Provider store={mockStore(mockInitialState)}>
          <myComponent history={mockHistory} />
        </Provider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });

  it("should redirect page on click of submitResponse", () => {
    const submitButton = wrapper.find(".submitResponse");
    submitButton.simulate("click");
    expect(mockHistory.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/home");
  });
});
```

Comment: worked :). But i have one doubt. can we able to check whether submitResponse is called or not.may be scenarios like that also can come right?. In this scenario you solution is apt like as you said.

Comment: I think, unless you had some other function or something performing the same functionality within the same component, then it shouldn't be too much of a concern whether your specific submit function has been called. If someone changed 'submitResponse' to 'handleSubmit' and forgot to update the call to the function in your `onClick`, for example, this test would fail as the side effects would not happen (i.e. the API call and the history.push would not be called).

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your test is you're mounting the component before you're spying on the it. So your spy gets bind with the original one instead of mock.
Try this,

```
import myComponent from "./myComponent ";

describe("Container", () => {
  const mockHistory = {
    location: {
      pathname: "/home",
    },
     push: jest.fn()
  };

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Provider store={mockStore(mockInitialState)}>
          <myComponent history={mockHistory} />
        </Provider>
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });
it("should redirect page on click of submitResponse", () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitResponse ');
    wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()
    wrapper.update()
    const submitButton = wrapper.find(".submitResponse");
    submitButton.simulate("click");
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
});
```

Hope this will work!!!

Comment: wrapper.update() didn't worked as well? In your solution only before simulating click, do wrapper.update() and check.

Comment: sorry. my mistske. Now it is returning typeError: Cannot read property 'submitResponse' of undefined

Comment: do we need to decalre that?

Comment: didn't worked yet. Cannot read property 'submitResponse' of undefined is returning.

Comment: when i consoled  myComponent.prototype it is showing undefined

Comment: Wait you have functional component, so it's correct you'll not get anything in prototype. I'll edit my answer wait

Comment: Just for the sake of testing, the initial solution that you had, can you add these two lines before simulating click.
wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()
wrapper.update()

Let me know if this works?

Comment: What about async keyword in front of props in submitResponse function?

Comment: removing async didn't worked . but Kieren Hughes solution worked,. he done a mock on history.push. Thanks for your help. i got some more concepts from your answer

Comment: That's also correct to test the cosequence of click. Cheers.